# Importing Matplotlib or Seaborn causes print statements to no longer output in terminal

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, module, seaborn

I have a small Python program that reads from a CSV and prints out a single column (using VSCode).

```
import pandas as pd

fields = ['Name']

somedata_df = pd.read.csv("somedata.csv")

print(somedata_df[fields])
```

The above code works as intended and prints out the "Name" column. Simply adding `import seaborn as sns` or `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` causes the program to run as usual with no warnings or errors, but it does not print anything to the terminal.

This issue arose from my exploration as to why I could not produce any plots in a different program. The same thing happened there - program ran without warnings or errors, but did not show any of the plots. No, I did not forget to use `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`.

Even running this example code from Seaborn fails to display a plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotib.pyplot as plt

sns.set()

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", col="time",
            hue="smoker", style="smoker", size="size",
            data=tips)

plt.show()
```

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: @JodyKlymak The default integrated terminal in VSCode.

Comment: Seems like an install/VS issue

Comment: @JodyKlymak Running the code in a Python Interactive Window appears to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still unsure as to why plots do not show up, and why importing either Matplotlib or Seaborn causes the regular terminal to stop displaying outputs, but selecting the code, right-clicking it, and choosing "Run Selection/Line in Python Interactive Window" works both for the original print statement and any plotting.